# How suitable is a Dahon folding bike for Indian road conditions?

Tags: reliability

I'm in the market for Dahon folding bike. I have narrowed down on the [Dahon SUV D6](http://dahon.com/mainnav/foldingbikes/single-view/bike/suv_d6.html) since it suits my budget. I would be carrying it around in trains on weekends to tourist towns in South India and roam around in it. Indian roads are notorious for their poor riding conditions. My concern is will the D6 (that is designed primarily for urban commuting) be able to handle a bump or two and be a reliable machine that I need it be during my vagrant outbursts. Since I haven't seen a Dahon first-hand yet and since I'll mostly be placing the order for it online, I'm a bit anxious.

[Dahon http://dahon.com/uploads/tx_dahonproducts/IMG_10256.png](http://dahon.com/uploads/tx_dahonproducts/IMG_10256.png)

[Dahon D6 http://dahon.com/uploads/tx_dahonproducts/IMG_10204.png](http://dahon.com/uploads/tx_dahonproducts/IMG_10204.png)

Comment: What I've read is that it's not suitable for much at all, due to the very poor geometry.  Never actually ridden one (and not particularly anxious to).  Compare to the geometry of the (much more expensive) Bike Friday, which has been used by many people in the US for long-distance tours.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think this bike would be a poor choice for a number of reasons.

- First, the small wheel size will accentuate the bad road
  conditions. Larger wheels will seem to smooth out the bumps a bit
  better.
- As has already been commented, folding bikes in general do not handle particularly well, which is not what you want on bumpy streets.
- Although this bike folds, that is the extent of its portability.
  The Dahon website says it weighs 31.7 pounds, so it's going to be
  difficult to heft even though it may fit a bit better on a train
  than a non-folding bike.
- My experience with Dahon is that you pay quite a bit for the
  foldability. It looks like this bike costs $300. When you consider that $300 is the starting point for "bike-shop brand" bicycles, a $300 folding bike is, frankly, using probably the lowest quality components possible. Not ideal for any riding environment and made even worse by rough roadways. I suspect this bike will cause you quite a few maintenance headaches.

I don't know anything about trains in India, but if it is possible to bring a non-folding bike onto a train there, I think you will be much better off overall. You will get more bike for the money, probably a lighter bike, and definitely larger wheels. My advice would be to shop around for something of the non-folding variety if your budget is $300. I would look at a mountain bike if the roads are extremely bad, but for more weight savings a hybrid would be an option.

I don't know the bike shop situation in India, but the folks at a bike shop will probably be able to guide you to something that is appropriate for your local riding conditions.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would emphasize for the OP that larger wheels handle bumps and potholes better. Those small wheels will just catch in a hole or on a bump, and throw the rider off. And they look *weak*, like they are intended to be ridden down my hallway.

Comment: Agreed. Re-reading what I originally wrote, I think I was too tempered in my comments about wheel size. Personally, I would not ride a bike with small wheels on bad roads. The 29er mountain bike movement was partially born of the logic that bigger wheels effectively reduce the size of the bumps and divots that you hit.

Comment: Thank you pjd for the comprehensive answer. Much appreciated. This makes me reconsider my options. I'll see what kind of bikes I can fit into a train and will try going for something with larger wheels. Thanks andy256 for the highlight.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is the availability of parts.

I have a Dahon in Tokyo and  the local bike shops there don't always have the 20" tubes and have to order away. You might want to bring a couple of inner tubes (and depending on how long you're there, some tires).

Also, while in Tokyo I broke a folding pedal off my Dahon. This is one of the weak areas of the standard Dahon design as it uses plastics/composites in the folding pedal. I had to wait a couple of weeks for this to be special ordered. If I had replaced it with a non-folding pedal, I could have had a replacement immediately, but then I couldn't fold the bike in half any more. I replaced it with a metal folding pedal that is much more solid.

In conclusion, if you'll be in India for a while you might want to stock up on:

- Inner tubes and a spare tire or two   (in addition to a patch kit)
- Spokes (20" wheels use small   spokes that are hard to find in remote areas)
- Other spare parts as  necessary

  - or have access to a friend who's willing to special   order parts in for you

That said, I like my Dahon as it's easy to fold, slip into its carry bag, and take on the train. Mine is one of the lighter versions, just around 12kg (25 pounds) so it's still luggable. I've taken it all over Japan, from northern Hokkaido to western Honshu.

Comment: Thank you RoboKaren for the helpful answer. I have to consider availability of spares for sure.